# How to save state of recyclerview in fragment in viewpager?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I have set up a ViewPager & TabLayout that have 3 fragments and one of them has a RecyclerView. I want to restore the RecyclerView's contents after the fragment is destroyed. 
The RecyclerView is populated from an API which I call in onViewCreated using AsyncTaskLoader. I want it to retain the data when rotating without re-using the API.

This is how I'm trying to do it:

```
    @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mListState = mLayoutManager.onSaveInstanceState();
    outState.putParcelable(LIST_KEY,mListState);
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
    mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_earthquake);
    mAdapter = new EarthquakeAdapter(getContext(), mList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    if (savedInstanceState != null){
        mListState = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(LIST_KEY);
        mLayoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState(mListState);
    } else {
        Bundle queryBundle = new Bundle();
        format = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
        String startDate = format.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        String endDate = format.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 86400000L));
        queryBundle.putString("startDate", startDate);
        queryBundle.putString("endDate", endDate);
        LoaderManager.getInstance(this).restartLoader(0, queryBundle, this);
    }
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
}
```

This doesn't work, when I rotate the device the RecyclerView is empty.
I'm also using FragmentStatePagerAdapter, if that matters.

Comment: add this in your activity in Manifest.xml :
`android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` it will tell system not to destroy and recreate your activity while rotating device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the items in the adapter

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    outState.putParcelableArrayList(ITEMS_KEY, mItems)
}
```

in onViewCreated method

```
if (savedInstanceState?.containsKey(ITEMS_KEY) == true) {
       mAdapter.setItems(savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList<YourModel>(ITEMS_KEY))
} else {
       // load data
}
```

Comment: This works well. I also had to implement Parcelable in my custom object. Thanks!